# Translating Sierpinski's carpet into a matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

As the title says, I'm trying to find general formulas to build Sierpinski's carpet into a matrix of 0s and 1s but can't find them.
This is how the matrix should look for size 3^2 by 3^2:
[image: Sierpinski's carpet into a matrix]

I've only found one for the center square and the top-left corner.
For any `n`, this piece of code works (I'm initializing the grid with 0s at the start and filling it with 1s):

```
for(k=3; k<=729; k=k*3)
    for(i=x/k+1; i<=2*x/k; i++)
        for(j=x/k+1; j<=2*x/k; j++)
            grid[i][j]=1;
```

I'm unsure of how to continue the problem.

Comment: If that code works, then what's your question?

Comment: That's only a piece of what I needed. That piece of code generated squares for only one corner of the grid. I needed to know how to form the other squares in the other corners as well. In the meantime I found the solution, but thanks for asking anyways.